# white question marks within black diamond

Tags: magento-1.9, character-encoding

As mentioned in the title i am dealing with the following problem, i see a special character in my `magento` store. The special character appears as white question mark within a black diamond. Is there a way to make that special character disappear??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SET NAMES uft8 as SQL query

Add this in header of your page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Depending on the charset that you are using.

Comment: i think i have tried that in the past but i'll give a go one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably there is something wrong with your translation files.
The CSV files for your language are (were not) saved in the UTF8 format, so all special chars like `è, í, É, Í, ó,` and so on are not saved properly.

Comment: i will check this out and give a feedback.